# Is there a way to reference the object that caused an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, reference

Trying to find a lazy way to handle part of my data validation through the use of exception handling. For instance, if the text in a textbox was supposed to be a string, the code tries to parse it into a string when its all numbers, it'll throw an exception. From the catch block, is there a way to reference the problem object and say... change its background color to yellow?

Comment: So you want to call `foo.Validate` inside of a `try` somewhere up in the callstack, and be able to get `foo` back?

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing exceptions to validate your string parsing.  Use the asp.net validation controls to determine if the input is text or numbers using RegEx.  This can be done without a postback.  If you require a postback, then when the validation control's IsValid is false, set the background color of your texbox (or whatever) to yellow.

Comment: well im thinking in terms of wiring up to an errorprovider. In java you can use GetSource to find the object that had the code which causes the exception. If i could reference that, i could trigger the errorprovider on its assigned control and set its text to the exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your textbox object, and actually also in your example textbox is not the one that caused exception.

WPF example:

```
int number;
try
{
    number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    textBox1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Although for this particular example it is better to use `TryParse` instead.

If your object is accesable only inside your Validate method and validate method failed, and you want to make this object available inside of `catch`, you need to implement custom exception that will have a field of type TextBox in this case.

**[Edit]**

I think I misunderstood the question.

Custom exception

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public TextBox TextBox { get; private set; }

    public MyException(TextBox textBox)
    {
        TextBox = textBox;
    }
}
```

Parse, Validate or whatever method:

```
public int Parse()
{
    try
    {
        return int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        throw new MyException(textBox1);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    int number;
    try
    {
        number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (MyException exception)
    {
        exception.TextBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
```

Comment: i guess this would be the closest thing to what I was referring to in java, only it doesn't seem to be reusable out of the box so to speak. I'm assuming I could rework this to just bring in an object and unbox it and GetType ... I'll tinker with it. I figured that being as C# is pretty much java, that it would have a similar method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to remember that it's not an object that causes an exception. It's a line of code that throws an exception.

You could create [**custom exceptions**](http://blog.gurock.com/articles/creating-custom-exceptions-in-dotnet/) that hold objects, and send back an object of choice. (or *this* object)

From MSDN: [**Designing custom exceptions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064.aspx)

Closest you can get with built-in functionality:

[**Exception.Source Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.source%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: i believe in java you can use GetSource to retrieve the parent object of the code that caused the exception. Theres nothing like this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's possible that the object which caused the exception is a private member of some object, and by allowing it to be exposed via an exception handler you'd be breaking the encapsulation of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you could create your own custom exception which could communicate the control being validated which could then enable you to do some layout changes on the control

But I think it would be cleaner to raise an event than to raise an exception, where the event then could communicate the object with the validation error. You could then perform the object layout change in the event subscriber.

The cleanest thing though would be to use the existing ASP.NET validation controls. The regex validator can perform the actual test of numeric/non numeric but lacks a place to hook up the layout change. For this purpose you can use the `CustomValidator` and bind the `ServerValidate` event and set control layout when errors are detected in that event. The

But should you choose to do the event based validation an attempt is shown below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Event args for the validation error. 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="ControlType">The control type accepted. (Can be 'Control´ for flexibility.</typeparam>
public class EvalidationErrorEventArgs<ControlType> : System.EventArgs
    where ControlType : Control
{
    ControlType ControlCausingException { get; private set; }

    public FormatException RaisedException { get; private set; }

    public EvalidationErrorEventArgs(ControlType controlCausingException, FormatException ex)
    {
        this.ControlCausingException = controlCausingException;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The validation error event.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="ControlType">The type of control to be communicated by the event.</typeparam>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
public delegate void ValidationErrorEvent<ControlType>(object sender, EvalidationErrorEventArgs<ControlType> e);

/// <summary>
/// Base validator, expects validation 
/// errors to be communicated as a FormatException. 
/// Other exception types are thrown.
/// </summary>
public abstract class TextBoxValidator
{
    public event ValidationErrorEvent<TextBox> ValidationError;

    /// <summary>
    /// Do validation. Raises event if format exception 
    /// occurs and listeners are registered. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBoxToValidate">Control to validate.</param>
    public void Validate(TextBox textBoxToValidate)
    {
        try
        {
            DoValidation(textBoxToValidate);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            if (ValidationError != null)
            {
                ValidationError(this, new EvalidationErrorEventArgs<TextBox>(textBoxToValidate, e));
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overwrite to implement the actual 
    /// validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="txt">Control to validate</param>
    protected abstract void DoValidation(TextBox txt);
}

/// <summary>
/// Performs validation of input controls content. 
/// </summary>
public abstract class IsTextValidator : TextBoxValidator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a text box to contain an integer value. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="txt">Control to validate</param>
    protected override void DoValidation(TextBox txt)
    {
        int.Parse(txt.Text);
    }
}
```